# Adobe LiveCycle Designer -- Center content in subform

Tags: adobe, position, center, livecycle, subform

I have a subform which wraps two (2) text fields. I set the subform to Flowed / Western Text so that the content goes from left to right. The problem is I want the subform (or the content) to be centered, and I can not find out how to do this. The reason I don't use positional is because the text inside of each of the two text fields is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is not a general solution but it still might solve your case of the problem:

Textfields can have their content centered horizontally and vertically. Stretch them to the width and height you want the text to be centered in and choose *center* for horizontal and *middle* for vertical alignment from the [paragraph palette](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/9.0/designerHelp/000434.html#1581237).

Since you work with two textfields, you can't make use of this feature to center both texts at once.

How about displaying both dynamic texts in one single textfield then?
You can do that using *[floating text](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/9.0/designerHelp/000357.html#1581107)*. This way you can display both texts and still have them centered horizontally and vertically.